# UIScrollView Glitch while detecting bottom of scroll view

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, swiftui, swift5

I have this custom view which creates a Scroll View in SwiftUI. I'm trying to detect the bottom of the view so i can call my `load()` function to load the next batch of data. The problem is:

My implementation detect the bottom, not when I reach the bottom but when: I reach the bottom and the I Pull up the screen, so I need to go a lot more than the bottom for it to be triggered. When the scrollbar is at the bottom nothing happens.

What is more weird is that, even with a single item, when I pull up(even thought there is no scrollbar), `load()` is called again.

Moreover, it is messing also with my `handleRefreshControl(sender: UIRefreshControl)`. When I pull up the screen this is triggered also. This should be triggered only on Scroll down not up.

I do not want my function to be called at this point.

[image]

but on this point. So when the scrollbar is at the end (or even a little bit before the end).

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomScrollView<Content: View, VM: LoadProtocol> : UIViewRepresentable {
    var width : CGFloat
    var height : CGFloat
    
    var viewModel: VM
    let content: () -> Content
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self, viewModel: viewModel)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
        let control = UIScrollView()
        control.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        control.refreshControl?.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.handleRefreshControl), for: .valueChanged)
        
        control.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        let childView = UIHostingController(rootView: content())
        
        childView.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
        
        control.addSubview(childView.view)
        return control
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) { }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
        var control: CustomScrollView<Content, VM>
        var viewModel: VM
        init(_ control: CustomScrollView, viewModel: VM) {
            self.control = control
            self.viewModel = viewModel
        }
        
        var fetchingMore = false
        
        func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            if (scrollView.contentOffset.y + 1) >= (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height) {
                if !fetchingMore {
                    beginFetchMore()
                }
            }
        }
        
        func beginFetchMore() {
            fetchingMore = true
            
            viewModel.load()
            
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                self.fetchingMore = false
            }
        }
        
        @objc func handleRefreshControl(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
            sender.endRefreshing()
            viewModel.refresh()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a tableview instead and then detecting if you've scrolled past the tableview? 
        ` let height = tableView.frame.size.height
        let contentYoffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let distanceFromBottom = scrollView.contentSize.height - contentYoffset
        if distanceFromBottom <= height ` or this might work for UIView

Comment: and to not trigger the refresh control you could add an extra check to see if the minY value of the refresh control is greater than 0 when scrolling ?  if distanceFromBottom <= height && RefreshControl.frame.minY > 0 {

Comment: i can not use a table view since i need the pull to refresh functionality and this is reused in s lot  of other Swiftui views. they are wrapped inside this.

Comment: try using scrollviewdidbeginDecelerating instead of scrollviewdid scroll and change    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y + 1) >= (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height) {
                if !fetchingMore { to         let height =  childview.frame.size.height
        let contentYoffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let distanceFromBottom = scrollView.contentSize.height - contentYoffset
        if distanceFromBottom <= height && refreshControl.frame.minY > 0 {

Comment: is childview my scrollView and what is refreshControl ?

Comment: Childview should be your Scrollview and refreshcontrol should be a stored refreshcontrol variable so you can reference it